# Install a Second IMU, Clearpath Husky

Tags: navigation, clearpath, husky, microstrain, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Community,

I am running a Clearpath Robotics Husky, and I would like to install a second IMU, a Microstrain 3DM-GX3-25. There is already a Microstrain 3DM-GX2 installed on the robot. How do I get the Husky to recognize the new IMU and also get the IMU to push messages into ROS?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220547/install-a-second-imu,-clearpath-husky/) by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, you should use package `microstrain_3dmgx2_imu` (http://wiki.ros.org/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu) to publish this new IMU. But to not to mix this one with the other IMU (possibly UM6), you should remap `/imu/data` topic of microstrain to another one. Like;

```
<node pkg="microstrain_3dmgx2_imu" type="imu_node" name="microstrain_3dmgx2_imu" output="screen">
        <remap from="/imu/data" to="/ms_imu/data" />
</node>
```

After these, you should include this new IMU into `robot_localization` via config (https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_control/config/localization.yaml).

For example you can add;

```
imu1: ms_imu/data
imu1_config: [false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false]
imu1_differential: true
imu1_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

This should implement your new IMU into your setup.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on 2015-11-11**:
Thanks a lot, Akif. I just had to plug the IMU into the USB port on the Husky and set the launch files up as you described. It's working now, except that I need to figure out how to calibrate the IMU.